# What is the fastest way to load data into a new CitusDB instance?

Tags: postgresql, citus

I'm following the instructions on [Scaling Out Data Ingestion](https://www.citusdata.com/docs/citus/5.0/performance/scaling_data_ingestion.html), with this command:

```
find . -type f | xargs -n 1 -P 320 sh -c 'echo $0 `copy_to_distributed_table -C $0 table_name`'
```

My cluster has a master and eight workers, each with two SSDs.  The table is spread across 320 shards.

Data loading is taking a very long time.  The average insertion rate seems to be about 750k per minute.  Is that normal or is there a way to speed it up?

The only thing I can think of is that I have replication enabled.  Should that be turned off for loading and then reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to use hash partitioning. If that is the case, we're deprecating `copy_to_distributed_table` in favor of distributed `COPY`. `COPY` provides a native PostgreSQL experience, resolves several known issues, and **improves ingest performance by more than an order of magnitude**. This is now available as of Citus 5.1, which [was released this month](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/18-sumedh-pathak/417-announcing-citus-51-improving-your-data-ingest-speed-and-experience) and is available in [the official PostgreSQL Linux package repositories](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) (PGDG).